# null value must be printed if there is no value for the xml element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am supposed to  write an XSLT for an XML document, for which if it has no parameter for an element, the XSLT must consider a null value. The output must be an XML document where the elements with no values in the original xml document, must be printed as `<tagName>Null</tagName>`

This is the xml document

```html
<salesOrderRequest>
<invoiceNo>1245</invoiceNo>
<PizzaType/>
<Price>1099</Price>
<Discount>234</Discount>
</salesOrderRequest>
```

This is my xslt

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLTransform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/salesOrderRequest">
   <xsl:value-of select="invoiceNo"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="PizzaType"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="Discount"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<salesOrderRequest>
    <invoiceNo>1245</invoiceNo>
    <PizzaType>Null</PizzaType>
    <Price>1099</Price>
    <Discount>234</Discount>
    </salesOrderRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLTransform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/salesOrderRequest/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="salesOrderRequest/*" priority="1">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="salesOrderRequest/*[.='']" priority="2">
     <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Michael. how does it transfer to the null template if there is no if condition.  Was just wondering.

Comment: It looks at all the matching template rules and selects the one with highest priority.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, for

try

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (normalize-space(PizzaType))
    then PizzaType
    else 'Null' "/>
```

or (if you don't want to accept `<PizzaType> </PizzaType>` as equivalent to `<PizzaType/>`)

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (PizzaType ne '')
    then PizzaType
    else 'Null' "/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="(PizzaType[. ne ''], 'Null')[1]"/>
```

If you require a solution in XSLT 1.0, you should tag your question that way.